# How to use .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to implement an .htaccess file so someone cannot access a directory in /var/www without being asked first for a password. I have read these two tutorials [here](https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess) and [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/), so i implemented an .htaccess file inside the file1 directory i wanted to protect which contains:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/file1/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and then a .htpasswd file inside the same directory with the command

```
sudo htpasswd -c /var/www/file1/.htpasswd user1
```

What have i done wrong??

Comment: What is *going* wrong?

Comment: When i enter the directory from the browser like `localhost/file1` it does not promt me for password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file). Very briefly: 
1. Create an .htaccess file in the directory you want to protect, for example `/var/www/my-protected-directory`
2. Paste the following inside

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/safedirectory/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

where AuthUserFile points to the location of the .htpasswd 
3. create the file with the format: `username:password` and you are done